# Why System.Windows.Forms.Control does not receive all the WM_ messages?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, sendmessage

I'm using [this approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc) to override `WndProc()` method in my custom Control. Why am I unable to catch `WM_SIZING`, `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`, `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE` messages? At low level isn't `System.Windows.Forms.Control` a standard window as all UI items? Does the .NET Framework eat some messages along the pipeline?

Thanks.

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE:
                WmEnterSizeMove();
                break;

            case WM_SIZING:
                WmSizing();
                break;

            case WM_SIZE: // I can only see some of these around during resize
                WmSize();
                break;

            case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
                WmGetMinMaxInfo();
                break;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: A `Control` could be about anything. Are we talking about a `Form`?

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Choose single not working case, produce [mcve] and ask question.

Comment: _Why am I unable to catch WM_SIZING, WM_GETMINMAXINFO, WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE messages?_

Comment: No idea, you didn't show [mcve] and didn't explain what mean "unable to catch" (do you set abreakpoint?). Probably you did something wrong.

Comment: You can find the sample using the link I provided at the beginning of the question.

Comment: Because that's the way the operating system works.  Only top-level windows ever get those messages, not child windows.  Forms, not controls.  Controls cannot be independently be min/maximized (so no WM_GETMINMAXINFO) and don't have the modal sizing loop that you activate by dragging an edge.

Comment: Add an answer, this is was the reason I was looking for.